# How to check if $('.name') contains a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, loops

I’d like to check if a specific value is in `$('.name')`. How can I achieve this? I can’t loop through $('.name'), because I already loop through an array to check if each entry is in `$('.name')`. It is possible that my array contains more object than `$('.name')`. Here is the code for better understanding:

```
let arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
let test = $('.name'); // <- contains multiple childs

for (let i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
    if (true) { // <- test contains arr[i]

    }
}
```

Comment: Which specific value do you need?

Comment: Please add code which you worked on

Comment: @KunalMukherjee added some code :).

Comment: @TiSer added some code :).

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```js
  const
      target = 'Some Text',
      query = $('.name'),
      check = ({ innerHTML }) => innerHTML.includes(target),
      result = Array.from(query).some(check);

  console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="name">Some Text</div>
```

Or without `Jquery`:

```js
const
      target = 'Some Text',
      check = ({ innerHTML }) => innerHTML.includes(target),
      result = [...document.querySelectorAll('.name')].some(check);

  console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="name">Some Text</div>
```

---

Basically you're right, the JQuery's query object contains additional elements besides array cells, but some capabilities with arrays are still available, such as `length`.
If you want to refer to elements found in Jquery as an array, simply use `Array.from`, which means you will write it like this: `Array.from($('.name'))` (Although in this case you actually have no need for Jquery, and you can use the built-in function `document.querySelectorAll`).

Comment: Isn't it possbile to convert `$('.name') to a string and then check with includes('abc')?

Comment: @fnm65404 Just search the inner text that the element contains? I changed, look now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts. I will remember that for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyup to check if the array has the user typed character or not.

```js
$(function() {
  const arr = ["a", "b", "c"],
    test = $('.name');

  $('.name').keyup(function(event) {
    const currentVal = $(this).val();
    const containsText = arr.some(x => x === currentVal);

    if (containsText)
      console.log('Contains value ' + currentVal);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="name" type="text" />
</body>

</html>
```